# How to use floggy with Android?

Tags: android

I am new to Android. I want to use database with Android. Is there any way to use floggy with Android?

Answer (score 2):

In fact, you don't have to use floggy. There is already a database system present on Android, using [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/). You can read more about it [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#db) in the android official documentation.